# Insertion sort with binary search not working properly

Tags: java, binary-search, insertion-sort

Here's the code

```
for(out=1; out< dictSize; out++){
   String temp = dict[out];
   in=out;
   int lowerBound = 0;
   int upperBound = in-1;
   int curIn;  

   while (lowerBound <= upperBound){
      curIn = (lowerBound+upperBound)/2;
      if(dict[curIn].compareTo(temp) > 0){
           dict[in] = dict[curIn]; 
           dict[curIn]=temp;
           upperBound = curIn-1;
       } else{
           if(dict[curIn].compareTo(temp) < 0){
                 lowerBound=curIn + 1;
            }  
       }         
    }
 }

 //status = "sorted";
 for(String v: dict){
      System.out.println(v);
 }
```

Here's the output which is not arranged properly:

```
animal

animal

barter

cases

code

dictionary

file

simon

this

crazy
```

What's wrong, how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you deal with array rather than linked list then it's not enough to exchange last element with middle one. You have to move whole part of array (for instance using System.arraycopy). So here is my version:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] dict = {"this", "cases", "animal", "barter", "animal",
            "file", "code", "dictionary", "simon", "crazy"};
    for (int out = 1; out < dict.length; out++) {
        String temp = dict[out];
        int indexToInsert = binarySearch(dict, 0, out - 1, temp);
        if (indexToInsert < out) {
            // Next call copies elements [indexToInsert, out-1]
            // to elements [indexToInsert+1, out] (shift to the right)
            System.arraycopy(dict, indexToInsert, dict, 
                    indexToInsert + 1, out - indexToInsert);
            dict[indexToInsert] = temp;
        }
    }

    //status = "sorted";
    for(String v: dict){
        System.out.println(v);
    }
}

public static int binarySearch(String[] dict, int lowerBound, 
        int upperBound, String value) {
    while (lowerBound <= upperBound){
        int curIn = (lowerBound + upperBound)/2;
        int compRes = dict[curIn].compareTo(value);
        // compRes reflects relation between dict[curIn] and value from
        // input parameters. compRes is {-1,0,+1} for cases when
        // dict[curIn] {<,=,>} value correspondingly. For details see: 
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String) .
        if (compRes == 0) {
            return curIn;
        } else if (compRes > 0){
            upperBound = curIn - 1;
        } else {
            lowerBound = curIn + 1;
        }
    }
    return lowerBound;
}
```

Another way is to use standard java implementation of binary search:

```
public static int binarySearch(String[] dict, int lowerBound, 
        int upperBound, String value) {
    int ret = Arrays.binarySearch(dict, lowerBound, upperBound + 1, value);
    return (ret < 0) ? -ret - 1 : ret;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain your version a little more cuz I got lost at compRes && System.arraycopy .

Comment: I added comments into code. Do you need more details?